# Java loop, yes or no while nested loop, new to java

Tags: java, loops, nested

```
import java.util.Scanner;

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
/**
 *
 * @author Leigh
 */
public class circle {

    private static String answer;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Opening statement
        System.out.println("Welcome to the Round Object Calculator\n"
                + "This program will calculate the area of a circle\n"
                + "     or the volume of a sphere.\n"
                + "The calculations will be based on the user input radius.");
        // CREATE SCANNER
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter C for circle or S for sphere: ");
        String a = input.next();
        //s or c loop
        if (a.equals("C")) {
            System.out.print("Thank you.  What is the radius of the circle (in inches): ");
            Double c = input.nextDouble();
            System.out.printf("The area of a circle with a radius of " + "is " + (3.14 * c * c) + " cubic inches");
        } else if (a.equals("S")) {
            System.out.print("Thank you.  What is the radius of the sphere (in inches):  ");
            Double s = input.nextDouble();

            System.out.printf("The volume of a sphere with a radius of" + s + "is " + (4 * 22 * s * s * s) / (3 * 7) + " cubic inches");

        }
        //yes or no loop
        System.out.print("Do you want to calculate another round object (Y/N)? ");
        String y = input.next();
        if (y.equals("Y")) {
            if (a.equals("C")) {
                System.out.print("Thank you.  What is the radius of the circle (in inches): ");
                Double c = input.nextDouble();
                System.out.printf("The area of a circle with a radius of " + "is " + (3.14 * c * c) + " cubic inches");
            } else if (a.equals("S")) {
                System.out.print("Thank you.  What is the radius of the sphere (in inches):  ");
                Double s = input.nextDouble();

                System.out.printf("The volume of a sphere with a radius of" + s + "is " + (4 * 22 * s * s * s) / (3 * 7) + " cubic inches");
            }
        }
        //default statement for N
        System.out.println("Thnk you");
    }
}
```

I'm very new to Java and I am having issues with this sections of code to calculate area of a sphere and circle. I'm trying to issue a loop so when the input is Y the above questions repeat until the user types in N to the question. Then when N is put in have the thank you statement and close out the program. Help you be greatly appreciated in achieving this goal.
I'm also having an issue with the numbers round to the nearest decimal point. Any help with that would also be greatly appreciated

Comment: Start by formatting the code so the structure and loops can be easily seen. An appropriate editor/IDE will auto-format the code. My motivation to inspect code that had not had the motivation applied to ensure that it is tidy is about zero..

Comment: Like I said I'm new to java, I did figure out how to format in Netbeans so hopefully someone will be willing to look over my code and help me out.

Comment: Okay, that looks better. The next step is to put the code to be looped in .. a loop. In this case a ["do..while"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html): `do { /* ask user for input and display output */ } while (/* user said to continue */)` is probably useful.

Comment: There are two loops, s and c loop commented and Y and N loop commented.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to repeat your calculation code block twice, like you have done. That is the purpose of the loop. You just have to write the code once, and then use a loop to run it again and again, so something like this using the do...while loop in your case:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

    /*
     * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
     * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
     * and open the template in the editor.
     */

    /**
     *
     * @author Leigh
     */
    public class circle {
        private static String answer;

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            String y = "";

            do {
                System.out.println("Welcome to the Round Object Calculator\n"
                        + "This program will calculate the area of a circle\n" + "     or the volume of a sphere.\n"
                        + "The calculations will be based on the user input radius.");
                // CREATE SCANNER
                Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
                System.out.print("Enter C for circle or S for sphere: ");
                String a = input.next();
                // s or c
                if (a.equals("C")) {
                    System.out.print("Thank you.  What is the radius of the circle (in inches): ");
                    Double c = input.nextDouble();
                    System.out.printf("The area of a circle with a radius of " + "is " + (3.14 * c * c) + " cubic inches");
                } else if (a.equals("S")) {
                    System.out.print("Thank you.  What is the radius of the sphere (in inches):  ");
                    Double s = input.nextDouble();

                    System.out.printf("The volume of a sphere with a radius of" + s + "is " + (4 * 22 * s * s * s) / (3 * 7)
                            + " cubic inches");

                }
                // yes or no
                System.out.print("Do you want to calculate another round object (Y/N)? ");
                y = input.next();
            } while (y.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"));

            System.out.println("Thnk you");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Now what issue are you having with rounding numbers?

Comment: Thank you very much. For calculating numbers I'm having an issue with them having 6 to 8 decimal places rather than two. I was told to use system.out.printf for this but I think I'm missing a component?

Comment: If you found my answer useful, please mark it as the selected answer.

Comment: As for the formatting, while using printf you have to specify placeholders within the string for your values using the % symbol, and in the placeholders, you can specify the number of decimals. 

So for example, for printing the radius and volume of the sphere to two decimal places, do something like this:


`System.out.printf("The volume of a sphere with a radius of %.2f is %.2f cubic inches", s, (4 * 22 * s * s * s) / (3 * 7));`

Comment: Thank you soo much. I could not for the life of me understand what I was missing.

Comment: @LeighB If you found the answer provided useful and it fixed your problem, please mark it as the accepted solution (check mark in the top left of the answer).